# Java package-only variables and inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, package

I have these two classes in different packages(named a and b)

```
package a;
import b.*;

public class Tree 
{
    int health = 100;

    public void show()
    {
        System.out.println(this.health);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Arb c = new Arb();
        //System.out.println(c.health); is not visible
        c.show();
    }
}

package b;
import a.*;
public class Arb extends Tree
{

}
```

I know that field ***health*** can't be accesed by an instance of type Arb because is not visible,so it doesn't exist for an instance of Arb. All that it inherited is the ***public void show()*** method. Ok until now.
But from my tests, calling method ***show*** through object ***c*** outputs the answer 100,as the initial value for a ***Tree*** object.

My problem with understanding this is: The method calls ***this.health*** ,so as long as object ***c*** calls this method, ***this*** = ***c***. But ***health*** shouldn't be visible...

Could someone explain what is actually happening there? Thank you!

Comment: *Everything* is inherited, not just `show()` (and `main`); it's just only the `public` things which are *visible* to be accessed in `Arb`.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement *"so it doesn't exist"* is incorrect. It exists, it's just not visible.

An instance of `Arb` is also an instance of `Tree`, and code in `Tree` can *see* the field, while code in `Arb` cannot see it.

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly said, the Arb class inherits the public `show()` method of the Tree class. When calling the method `show()` of the class Arb you are actually calling the `show()` method in Tree. Because this method can see the field `health` it can also print it's value.